# How to add command line dependencies using CMake

Tags: vala, cmake

I'm building a Vala app that uses `youtube-dl` command line. How do I make sure that it is installed when someone installs the app?

In other words: Looking at the CMake build documentation, what is the best way to add a command line dependency?

https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started#the-build-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`find_program`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_program.html) to look for the executable, then check the result. So something like

```
find_program(YOUTUBE_DL youtube-dl)
if(NOT YOUTUBE_DL)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "youtube-dl is required")
endif()
```

Comment: Is there a way to install the executable if the program is not found?

Comment: Nothing built in.  You could conceivably write some code to do it, but obviously it would vary by package manager, and I don't know what you'd do on Windows.